# How to receive many bytes on arduino form java

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port

I would like to receive an array of bytes on my Arduino, those being sent by java. I know the java code works because I have already tried it with an other arduino project, but i lost the arduino code for this and can't make it work again. My board is an Uno if that helps. Any tip would help, even if it's not a fully working program.

I have already tried a few ways to code it. I know I used SerialEvent().

Here is the java code and the last iteration of my arduino program. The problem is that SerialEvent doesn't seem to trigger because the yellow LED never turns on as it should.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3");

    sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);
    sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

    if(sp.openPort()) {
        System.out.println("Port is open");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Port failed to open");
        return;
    }

    byte[] message = {65, 66, 65};

    sp.getOutputStream().write(125); //Triggers serialEvent on Arduino
    sp.getOutputStream().flush();
    Thread.sleep(2000); //Waits for serialEvent to Trigger

    for(int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        sp.getOutputStream().write(message[i]); //Sends the message
        sp.getOutputStream().flush();
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    sp.getOutputStream().write(126); // Tells the Arduino the whole 
                                            message is sent
    sp.getOutputStream().flush();

        //I did everything needed to close the port etc, but didin't put it to 
          reduce the amount of code
```

//Arduino code:

```
byte message[200];
int GREEN = 4;
int BLUE = 3;
int YELLOW = 2;

void setup() {
  byte message[200];
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(20000);
  while(!Serial);

}

void loop() {
}

void SerialEvent(){
  digitalWrite(YELLOW, HIGH);
  int i = 0;
  delay(2000);
  while(Serial.available()){
    byte tmpByte = (byte)Serial.read();
    if(tmpByte != 126){
      message[i] = tmpByte;
      i++;
    }else{
      digitalWrite(YELLOW, LOW);
      ExecuteAlg(message); //Function that works correctly
    }
  }
}
```

The Arduino should put the received data in a byte array.

Thanks for any help.
If you need extra info, please ask, this is my first question and I don't know what to put exactly

Comment: No... the problem is that you have a broken mix of delays and events.  You need to learn how to write *stateful* serial receive code, possible with a *timeout* but without any mistaken use of delay()

Comment: I figured out a way that works while still using delays, but tbanks, I'll try to get rid of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is that you have written the serial event function as follows

```
void SerialEvent(){
```

instead of

```
void serialEvent(){
```

To be specific, the 1st character is supposed to be small case.
Check the serial event docs for more info
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent